# Como puedo usar una variable dinamica en un condicional "if" de javascript

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, lógica

Estoy intentando manejar la variable cont como una variable dinamica que cambie cada vez que se cumpla la condicion dada, actualmente esta condicion solo se cumple en el primer caso por lo que surge mi pregunta, como puedo hacer que la variable cont cambie cada vez que se cumple la condicion, para que este proceso pueda repetirse la veces que sea necesario.

```
var vector = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
vector[i] = i * 880;
                              }
 var cont=880;
if(cont == vector[cont/880]) { 
    //Cargar configuracion
                                                      });
    document.getElementById('bodie').onkeypress = function() {
       //ejecutar accion
    }
     //cambia el valor de la variable cont
    cont=cont+880;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es el punto, pero tendrias que declarar la variable fuera del `for`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cont=880;
var subCont = 880;
var vector = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  vector[i] = i * subCont;
  
  if(vector[i] % cont == 0) { 
    //Cargar configuracion
                                                
     //cambia el valor de la variable cont
    cont += subCont;
  }
  
}

document.body.onkeypress = function() {
    console.log(cont);
}
```

No se si es eso lo que deseabas hacer, (Ese valor que vez en pantalla es el contenido de la varible cont), pero por otro lado, nunca te recomiendo que pongas un eventListener dentro de un condicional (Ponlos por fuera de estas), por otro lado, ¿Tienes creado en el html un elemento llamado bodie al que le haces focus para que se ejecute el evento onkeypressed?, por que si no, imagino que estabas queriendo añadirle la función a la etiqueta body del documento.

Que para apuntar a esta, no debes usar document.getElementById, solo debes usar document.body, esta como tal es la referencia al body de la pagina.

el valor de la variable cont cambia 11 vecez dependiendo de la condición (Yo asumí que la condición es que al dividir el valor que tiene actualmente el vector en 880, su residuo sea cero, (Es decir que sea multiplo exacto de 880)), de todas maneras no se entiende muy bien que es exactamente lo que requieres hacer con la variable cont y la condición se entiende aún menos, ya que al colocar vector[cont/880] es lo mismo que simplemente colocar vector[i], ¿No estarás querriendo mas bien usar una **función** con cierto parámetro para almacenar un valor dinámico en la variable cont y dependiendo de ese valor hacer esas asignaciones a la variable vector y luego mostrarlas?, si es así, editare el código para realizar algo parecido con tu código.